# VSC snippets placeholder choices not loading

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

As the title says, I'm having problems with VSC's snippets placeholder choices as it gets stuck loading and I never get any of the options.

At the moment I'm testing with a really simple snippet:

```
    "console.log": {
        "scope": "javascript,typescript",
        "prefix": "cl",
        "body": [
            "console.${2|log,table,count,dir,error,info|}(${TM_SELECTED_TEXT:`${1:Here}`});"
        ],
        "description": "Log output to console"
    },
```

And the previous snippet ends with my second placeholder never showing the options

[image]

Any ideas of how to correct this? I already tried changing the followings settings as some post talked about them, but it didn't work:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A known issue, see [Github Issue: Code snippet "Choice" feature no longer working](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/144362)

> A fix for this will be in next VS Code Insiders. Also, this will be
> part of a 1.65.x recovery release.

The fix for the `choice` issue is in v1.65.2 and works for me.

---

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish with this part:

```
${TM_SELECTED_TEXT:`${1:Here}`}
```

I don't think `${TM_SELECTED_TEXT:...}` is allowed.  It seems to just skip over the first tabstop for that reason.  What were you trying to accomplish with that part of the snippet?

Comment: At first, I thought we had to wait for July…  Thanks for the information!